# grid beforeedit not working for checkboxes

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid with an editable **text column** and an editable **boolean column**.

```
    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: '1',
            header: 'String',
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            header: 'Boolean',
            dataIndex: '2'
        }
    ],
```

I would like to do some checking before I allow someone to edit a cell, so I implement the **beforeedit** function like so :

```
    listeners: {
        beforeedit: function (e) {
            alert('hi')
        }
    }
```

The beforeedit fires when I try and edit a text column, but for a checkbox it does not.

Why?

Fiddle demonstrating my problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/S8Tgm/16/

Comment: i looked at checkchange event on the checkbox column. Works, but won't fire before the edit event.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out :

```
            {
                xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                header: 'Boolean',
                dataIndex: '2',
                listeners: {
                    beforecheckchange: function() {
                        if (condition)
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

the checkcolumn needs a **[beforecheckchange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn-event-beforecheckchange)** listener.